# VSI metrics sending to IBM-cloud-monitoring

Tags: ibm-cloud, monitoring

I've followed the link and installed collectd on my VSI. 
[Instruction](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-monitoring/send-metrics/conf_monitoring_plugin.html#conf_monitoring_plugin)

However, it cannot upload metrics to monitoring service.

logs:

*Jan 6 14:53:45 hkg collectd[3689]: [WARN] IBMCM plugin:client.go:334: Sending 154 metrics in Buffer. Jan 6 14:53:45 hkg collectd[3689]: [NOTICE] IBMCM plugin:client.go:490: Connecting to https://metrics.au-syd.bluemix.net:9095 Jan 6 14:53:45 hkg collectd[3689]: [ERROR] IBMCM plugin: client.go:514: Failure connecting to https://metrics.au-syd.bluemix.net:9095: dial tcp: too many colons in address https://metrics.au-syd.bluemix.net:9095 Jan 6 14:53:45 hkg collectd[3689]: [WARN] IBMCM plugin:client.go:445: Can not get socket. Sleep 5 seconds and try again.*

It seems my metrics cannot upload to the https://metrics.au-syd.bluemix.net:9095 How do I fix it and successfully upload the metrics to IBM Cloud Monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@owhc - I suspect your configuration is not correct.  The Host field of the IBMCloudMonitoring configuration should not have https prefix.

Should look something like :

```
<Plugin IBMCloudMonitoring>
   <Endpoint "au">
     Host "metrics.au-syd.bluemix.net"
     Port 9095
     ApiKey "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     RateCounter false
     ScopeId "s-<your-space-guid>"
  </Endpoint>
</Plugin>
```

If that doesn't solve it - post your config without the space and apikey and we can dig some more...

Comment: Thanks! It works. I know there is my account type invalid.
Jan 12 02:13:24 hkg collectd[13950]: [ERROR] IBMCM plugin: client.go:424: Failed acknowledge due to error in metrics. Ignoring compressed pack. Sequence: 0. BXNMSMG02E: Metrics can only be accepted on a paid plan